# Proving that if $V$ is an inner product space and $U_1, U_2$ are subsets, then $U_1 \subset U_2$ if and only if $U^{\perp}_2 \subset U^{\perp}_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $V$ is an inner product space and $U_1, U_2$ are subsets, then I'd like to show that $U_1 \subset U_2$ if and only if $U^{\perp}_2 \subset U^{\perp}_1$. I can show the first forward direction, by first taking $w \in U^{\perp}_2$. Then, $w$ must be a vector where $<w, u_2> = 0$ for all $u_2 \in U_2$. But, since $U_1 \subset U_2$, then $<w, u_1> = 0$ for all $u_1 \in U_1$. Hence, $w \in U^{\perp}_1$.

I am not sure how to show the opposite direction. My proof is as follows:

Take $u_1 \in U_1$. Now, let $w \in U^{\perp}_2$. Then, $<w,u_2> = 0$ for all $u_2 \in U_2$. But, $U^{\perp}_2 \subset U^{\perp}_1$, and so $w \in U^{\perp}_1$ as well. Hence, $<w,u_1> = 0$ for all $u_1 \in U_1$. After this, I am not sure how to complete the proof. Am I in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: The statement is equivalent to $(U^\perp)^\perp = U$, and that is only guaranteed if $V$ is finite dimensional.  So your proof in the other direction probably requires choosing a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about the proof of the opposite direction as following the same structure as your forward direction proof.  In the forward direction, you first chose an arbitrary member of the set you wanted to show was smaller.  Then you used the definition of orthogonal subspace and carried on.

To prove the opposite direction, assume $U_2^\perp \subset U_1^\perp$.  Then for an arbitrary $u_1\in U_1$, we must have for all $w\in U_1^\perp$, $\langle u_1,w \rangle = 0$.  This statement is also true if we restrict $w$ to any subset of $U_1^\perp$, namely $U_2^\perp$.  Since $u_1$ is orthogonal to an element of $U_2^\perp$, $u_1$ must belong to the orthogonal complement of $U_2^\perp$ (otherwise known as $U_2^{\perp^\perp}$).

If you know (or can show) that $X = X^{\perp^\perp}$, then you're done.